# error in executing jar from commandline

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath, javaagents

When I fire the following from command line:
    D:\workspace 2\project\lib>java -javaagent:myagent.jar -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. AgentMain

I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.VerifyError: method(init) (Ljava/lang/String;) V not found 
java.lang.NullPointerException
Couldnot  find the main class AgentMain. Program will exit.
```

I have all the files and jar in the working directory. AgentMain is the compiled class that I put it here from the bin folder. I dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would check first whether the Agent is implemented OK?

You did follow the structure as set forth in [java.lang.instrument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) (`public static void premain(String agentArgs);`) including the MANIFEST entries? And there's no way that the Agent can throw NPEs during initialization?

Also, you may want to try out wheter it's the Agent or the AgentMain.class, by running `java -javaagent:myagent.jar -cp asm-all-3.3.jar;. -version`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the classpath to the current folder (-cp . ) ?